# Display spectrum of region of interest with Rasterio and Geopandas

Tags: python, image-processing, geopandas, spectrum, rasterio

I believe this is a very simple question, but for some reason I really struggle with finding the way to do that.

I have plot a satellite image that has 13 bands  and shapefile that located on top of it, using Rasterio and Geopandas as following:

```
shapefile = gpd.read_file('ROI.shp')


# plots both elements
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))

ax = rasterio.plot.show(src.read([4,3,2]),transform=src.transform,title='Image- bands 4,3,2 ',vmin=0,vmax=30000,with_bounds=True, ax=ax)
shapefile.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

and this is the table of the shapefile:

```
id  ROI geometry
0   4   Urban   POLYGON ((34.45501 31.53714, 34.48213 31.52649...
1   2   Sea POLYGON ((34.41933 31.54509, 34.40629 31.50923...
2   3   Agriculture MULTIPOLYGON (((34.49357 31.36081, 34.49463 31
```

My question is, **is there any way I can plot the spectum of the region of interest I have created?** e.g the sea, the agriculture and the urban area?
I want to get in the end line chart that has spectrum.
The only way I could think about is to rasterize the shapefile and then to pandas and to plot it, I believe ther emsut be better way to get the same results with Rasterio.

**my desired output is line chart when X axis is the bands of the image (or the wavelength) and the Y axis is the value on that band.**

Comment: Hi! I am not quite sure about your output. I understood the following: 
For the the combined ROI (Urban + ...) you would like to have one histogram with 13 bars (one per band), each bar showing the sum (?) of all pixels covered by your ROI in that band? Is this correct?